# Basic Question. What's the difference between a circumference and modulus of e^(iz)

Tags: complex-analysis

We know Modulus of e^(iz) is 1 but circumference is 2*pi*r

is modulus of e^(iz) multiplied with the angle it has rotated equal to circumference?

modulus of e^(iz) calculates the distance of entire closed circular curve.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: $\|e^{i\theta}\|=1 = $ radius of a unit circle $= \dfrac {\text{circumference}}{2\pi}$.  And $\|\theta e^{i\theta}\| =$ arc length.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Thoughtso, embarassing thanks

Comment: $|e^{iz}|=|e^{i(x+iy)}|=|e^{-y}e^{ix}|=e^{-y}$

Answer (score 0):

In real analysis and linear algebra the set $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the set of all points from distance $1$ from the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

On the other hand, $\{e^{i\theta}\,|\, \theta\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ also represents all the vectors in $\mathbb{C}$ (which is a vector space and a normed space) with radius $1$.

The thing is that, formally speaking, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ aren't the same space even though they are **very** similar! In fact, they are **isomorphic** as vector spaces and **isometric** as normed spaces, which is enough to think of them as almost identical spaces for any geometric purpose.

For this reason, we can picture the complex numbers as if we were working in the usual real plane and we can identify both *circles* and think of them as the same object, even though they aren't.